# Multiple queries in MongoDB (mongoose) before returning a JSON object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a MERN app. I have a one-to-many many-to-many relationship with Users and Organizations. I'm trying to create a function that returns all the organizations a user belongs to.

In my routes folder, I have

```
export const getOrganizations = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const currentUser = await User.findById(req.user.id)
    
    let organizations = [];
    await currentUser.organizationIds.forEach(async orgId => {
      let organization = await Organization.findById(orgId);
      console.log(organization)
      organizations.push(organization);
    })
    console.log("ORGS")

    res.status(200).json(organizations);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: error.message
    });
  }
}
```

I think the solution is using await and async, since right now my console is logging "ORGS" and sending a response before the organizations in my forEach log. But I'm not sure exactly how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with async callback to forEach function. Use for loop instead in which you can use await without skipping to wait for async code. ex:

```
for(let i = 0; i < currentUser.organizationIds.length; i++) {
   let organization = await Organization.findById(currentUser.organizationIds[i]);
   console.log(organization)
   organizations.push(organization);
}
```

Or you can go with using the map function and storing all promises in an array then using `Promise.all` to wait for all of them to finish. Ex.:

```
const fetchOrg = async orgId => {
  let organization = await Organization.findById(orgId);
  console.log(organization)
  organizations.push(organization);
}
let promises = currentUser.organizationIds.map(orgId => fetchOrg(orgId))
await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: The for loop worked, but I'm not sure why the for loop worked when the forEach didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that inside your `User` model, the `organizationIds` property is an array of ObjectIds of the Organization schema, something like this

```
organizationIds: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Organization' }]
```

If that is the case, you can simply [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) the organizationIds property

```
export const getOrganizations = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const currentUser = await User.findById(req.user.id).populate('organizationIds');
    
    res.status(200).json({organizations: currentUser.organizationIds});
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: error.message
    });
  }
}
```